# What will happen if I put my ESC's BEC black wire to ground and yellow/white wire to 5v pin directly

Tags: pi-3, electronics, dc-motor

I wanted to do some experiment with raspi, ESC and BLDC motor.
I am able to run my motor using servo tester.

But I was curious what will happen if I connect ESC's BEC to Raspi's GND and 5v output directly. will it burn the system or motor will receive a throttle.

I already endup burning a ESC and motor during my learning. So I am little afraid to try this.

Comment: This is more suitable for https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Start by drawing a schematic, many questions go away on their own when you've drawn a diagram.

Comment: Make sure you investigate whether you need to use [a flyback diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_diode) first -- I'd guess the ESC probably includes this but I do not know much about them.

Answer (score 0):

If you power via the microUSB socket (through the polyfuse) there isn't likely to be much "juice" left for a motor.  Perhaps one and a half amps on a Pi3, half an amp on a Pi3.  If your motor is happy with that you are good to go.

Of course if you power via the 5V and ground pins on the expansion header it depends on the spare capacity of your power supply (after the Pi takes what it needs).

If you draw too much the Pi will crash.  I don't see how either method can damage an ESC/motor so I presume your damage was caused differently.